# Breeze Datatype.Binary: what is it for and how to use it?

Tags: breeze

I was looking for a way to upload file to server along with saving entity and came across this Datatype.Binary for entity property, but did not find any information or usage example. Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see one usage example in the DocCode sample under the Northwind model. It is used to describe the Category.Picture data property where it's backed by a `varbinary` Sql data type at the db layer and `byte[]` on the conceptual model layer.

Comment: Thanks for search direction! There was no usage example of binary property on client side in that documentaion. I had to find out value format for binary property - it is base64string. So we have to manually load file from file input with FileReader.readAsDataUrl and get pure base64string from dataUrl. I thought, breeze could do this part for us.